# Converting OkHttp to use the Gradle build system

Tags: android, maven, gradle, okhttp

I have an Android project where I need to modify the source for OkHttp library. Right now they are using Maven. I ran into problems trying to use the default conversion into a Gradle project, specifically around the maven templating plugin. Has anyone had any success converting OkHttp to Gradle from maven?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to convert this to Gradle. There was a maven plugin for creating Java classes from a java-templates folder in one of the projects. I am using a specific version of OkHttp, so I created a new class based on the version.

There were also a number of failing tests around the MockHttpService and http2/Spdy. I either commented out those tests or altered them so they would pass. I am not using http2 or Spdy. Here is a link to the fork I created;

https://github.com/Swyft/okhttp/tree/swyftdev